# get random key/value pairs from json objects javascript (p5.js)

Tags: javascript, arrays, p5.js

How can I get random objects and get random key/value pairs from an array of multiple objects .json file?

I have a p5.js script that loads a json file that contains an array of multiple objects with 11 key/value pairs each. I can get random objects but I also need to get random key/valeu pairs to use as strings.

I don't have enough code skills to figure out a way to randomly sort between the random object and random key/valeu pairs. Any thoughts on this?

Thanks in advance.

**sample json:**

```
{
  "entries": [
    {
      "area": "0",
      "qtd": "3",
      "author": "FERNANDES, C. E. de M.",
      "title": "Fundamentos de física para geociências.",
      "subTitle": "xxxxx",
      "qtdPag": "v.",
      "edition": "xxxxx",
      "isbn": "ISBN 9788571931596.",
      "edPlace": "Rio de Janeiro:  Interciência,  2007.",
      "cdu": "53 F363f  Ac.1028543",
      "areaKnow": "Pre-catalogação"
    }
]
}
```

**p5.js code:**

```
var data;
var fontRegular;

function preload() {

    fontRegular = loadFont("assets/RobotoMono-Medium.ttf");
    data = loadJSON("assets/data-bce-final.json");
}

function setup() {

    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    setText();
    setInterval(setText, 5000);
}

function setText() {

    var entries = data.entries;
    var randomEntries = entries[Math.floor(Math.random() * entries.length)]; // get random item

    background(255);
    noStroke();
    fill(80, 227, 194);
    fill(100);
    textSize(30);
    textFont(fontRegular);

    text(
        // random version
        randomEntries.author + "\n" +
        randomEntries.title + "\n" +
        randomEntries.subTitle + "\n" + "\n" +
        randomEntries.edPlace + "\n" +
        randomEntries.areaKnow + "\n" + "\n" +
        randomEntries.cdu, 50, 60, windowWidth - 150);
}

function draw() {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are saying you want to get a random entry from your `entries` variable. If that is the case all you need to do is do the following:

```
var randomEntries = Object.keys(entries)[Math.floor(Math.random() * entries.length)];
```

The `Object.keys()` function will return an array of the keys which you can reference like any other array. You can then use the randomly generated key to get the values you want. If you want to get a random value, use `Object.values()`.

Hopefully that is what you were looking for, I wasn't super sure because of the wording.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I think this solved my problem.

Comment: Glad it helped!